# WinRT API "Windows.UI.ViewManagement" for Electron JS?

Tags: javascript, electron, windows-runtime

I'm trying to use this WinRT API code on electron with javascript. Is there a way to implement it?
I've seen NodeRT and Native addons but "Windows.UI.ViewManagement" is not available.

Code:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsScreenCaptureEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

That API is only for UWP apps and not for Electron apps. Some APIs can be used by all apps but some Windows Runtime APIs only work with UWP apps.